# How does Scikit learn KNN handle categorical input variables?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, regression, k-nn, one-hot-encoding

In some articles, it's said knn uses hamming distance for one-hot encoded categorical variables. Does the scikit learn implementation of knn follow the same way.

Also are there any other ways to handle categorical input variables when using knn.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html), the `KNeighborsClassifier` from scikit-learn uses minkowski distance by default.
Other metrics can be used, and you can probably get a decent idea by looking at the docs for scikit-learn's [`DistanceMetric` class](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.DistanceMetric.html#sklearn.metrics.DistanceMetric)

Comment: ok. minkowski distance can be used for continuous input variables. but what about discrete/categorical input variables?

Comment: No free lunch, so it's hard to give a straight answer. But I would experiment with 'jaccard' and 'matching'. They are also in the docs, so should work like a charm.